# Exception calling loadfile with 1 argument(s) the module was expected to contain an assembly manifest

Tags: powershell

I have a fairly straightforward PowerShell script that checks the version of an assembly.  Everything worked fine for me in Windows 10, but failed for my testers running Windows 7.

On windows 7 I get the error:

> exception calling loadfile with 1 argument(s) the module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be the version of powershell.  I installed Powershell 5.1 on Windows 7 and the errors went away.

Surprisingly there weren't any obvious solutions to this out there.  I wasted some time trying 32 and 64 bit versions of powershell and changing the build configuration for the assembly.  Hope this helps someone.